# Issue in minikube docker --> ERROR: http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main: DNS lookup error #560

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kubectl, minikube, amazon-ecr

I am using minikube configured docker. But when i am building docker image, which is giving an error **ERROR: http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main: DNS lookup error**. But if i am building docker image without minikube it is working and giving desire output. can any one help me to solve above issue.

As per my understanding issue occurs with minikube.

I am also providing DockerFile below

```
# Image Used
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

# Get dependent packages
RUN apk update && apk add git && apk add make

# First Stage: Builds the app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Run the custom Makefile to manage build flags and inject
RUN make docker_build

# Second Stage: Copies the binary and requirements and runs the app
FROM alpine AS bin
......

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./my_service"]
```

Comment: I'd reckon you are using `minikube` that uses a `Docker` driver.  I do not see the connection between the minikube usage and the building process. Are you running your build process inside of `minikube`? Could you please provide the detailed list of steps that you've followed?

Comment: yes i am using minikube to build Docker image

Comment: I'd reckon you could have some network connectivity issues between your `minikube` and the *Internet*. As you haven't provided the details about your infrastructure and steps that you've run it could be hard to pinpoint where exactly the issue lies. I'd recommend you to check the networking of your `minikube`. Can it connect to external sources, can it pull other images etc.